# How to implement an [GoF]-ish Abstract Factory Pattern using an IoC like Ninject

Tags: design-patterns, ninject, inversion-of-control, named-scope, abstract-factory

### Abstract

When the design requires an "Abstract Factory Pattern" like stated by the [GoF] including several products and over some product families, then setting up an IoC can become a bit tricky. Especially when the specific factory implementations need to be dispatched by runtime parameters and shared among some subsequent components.

Given the follwing API, i was trying to set up my IoC (Ninject in this case) to retrieve `Configuration` objects configured through a `IConfigurationFactory`. The configuration stores an `IFactory` instance whoose implementation is determined by a runtime parameter of type `ProductFamily`. Afterwards the product types created by the factory inside of the configuration should always match the requested `ProductFamily`. The subgraph, consisting of the `Component` class holds the same `IFactory` per `Configuration`.

```
public enum ProductFamily { A, B }
public interface IProduct1 { }
public interface IProduct2 { }
public interface IFactory
{
    IProduct1 CreateProduct1();
    IProduct2 CreateProduct2();
}
public class Configuration
{
    public readonly IFactory factory;
    public readonly Component component;
    public Configuration(IFactory factory, Component component)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
        this.component = component;
    }
}
public class Component
{
    public IFactory factory;
    public Component(IFactory factory) { this.factory = factory; }
}
public interface IConfigurationFactory
{
    Configuration CreateConfiguration(ProductFamily family);
}
```

### Tests

To clarify the intended behaviour i have added my test code writte in vstest. But forehand some additions, thanks to @BatterBackupUnit for asking these nitty details:

- The factories do only need the `ProductFamily` as a parameter to choose between the implementations, nothing else
- Every `Configuration` and its subsequent objects like the `Component`, share the same factory instance

So i hope this helps :)

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var configFac = ComposeConfigurationFactory();
    // create runtime dependent configs
    var configA = configFac.CreateConfiguration(ProductFamily.A);
    var configB = configFac.CreateConfiguration(ProductFamily.B);

    // check the configuration of the factories
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(configA.factory.CreateProduct1(), typeof(Product1A));
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(configB.factory.CreateProduct1(), typeof(Product1B));
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(configA.factory.CreateProduct2(), typeof(Product2A));
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(configB.factory.CreateProduct2(), typeof(Product2B));

    // all possible children of the configuration should share the same factory
    Assert.IsTrue(configA.factory == configA.component.factory);
    // different configurations should never share the same factory
    var configA2 = configFac.CreateConfiguration(ProductFamily.A);
    Assert.IsTrue(configA.factory != configA2.factory);
}
```

This qestion has already been solved therefore i removed all the unnecessary fluff.

Thanks to @BatteryBackupUnit for your time and effort
Best regards

Isaias

Comment: Do you really need the factory at all? Why don't you just inject the product into a consumer if it's needed?

Comment: Do the factories need some other configuration dependent implementation other than "selecting" the correct specific product type (i.E. FactoryA => Product1A, FactoryB => Product1B)? .

Comment: Does configuration A need the same Factory instance twice (configuration.factory == configuration.component.factory) or is it enough when they are of the same type?

Comment: @Steven : In this example the Factory is not really "needed" to do a heavy task but that is not the point. The point is that there is a unit test which defines how the factory should look like. This on the other hand implies that it is needed to make the code compile and run as expected.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit I will add some clarifications to your questions and edit the given example explanation a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following alternative passes all your tests while remaining fairly generic.
The bindings define all configuration dependencies. The only non-binding code which is ninject specific is the IConfigurationFactory which puts the necessary configuration information (=>ProductFamily) on the ninject context.

You will need the following nuget packages to make this code compile:

- Fluent Assertions
- Ninject
- Ninject.Extensions.ContextPreservation
- Ninject.Extensions.Factory
- Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope

Here's the code:

```
using System.Linq;
using FluentAssertions;
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Activation;
using Ninject.Extensions.Factory;
using Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope;
using Ninject.Modules;
using Ninject.Parameters;
using Ninject.Planning.Targets;
using Ninject.Syntax;

public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load<AbstractFactoryModule>();

        var configFac = kernel.Get<ConfigurationFactory>();

        // create runtime dependent configs
        var configA = configFac.CreateConfiguration(ProductFamily.A);
        var configB = configFac.CreateConfiguration(ProductFamily.B);

        configA.factory.CreateProduct1().Should().BeOfType<Product1A>();
        configB.factory.CreateProduct1().Should().BeOfType<Product1B>();

        configA.component.factory.Should().Be(configA.factory);

        configA.factory.Should().NotBe(configB.factory);
    }
}

public enum ProductFamily { A, B }
public interface IProduct1 { }
public interface IFactory
{
    IProduct1 CreateProduct1();
}

public class Product1A : IProduct1 { }
public class Product1B : IProduct1 { }

public class Configuration
{
    public readonly IFactory factory;
    public readonly Component component;
    public Configuration(IFactory factory, Component component)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
        this.component = component;
    }
}
public class Component
{
    public IFactory factory;
    public Component(IFactory factory) { this.factory = factory; }
}

public interface IConfigurationFactory
{
    Configuration CreateConfiguration(ProductFamily family);
}

public class ConfigurationFactory : IConfigurationFactory
{
    private readonly IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot;

    public ConfigurationFactory(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)
    {
        this.resolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
    }

    public Configuration CreateConfiguration(ProductFamily family)
    {
        return this.resolutionRoot.Get<Configuration>(new AbstractFactoryConfigurationParameter(family));
    }
}

public class AbstractFactoryConfigurationParameter : IParameter
{
    private readonly ProductFamily parameterValue;

    public AbstractFactoryConfigurationParameter(ProductFamily parameterValue)
    {
        this.parameterValue = parameterValue;
    }

    public ProductFamily ProductFamily
    {
        get { return this.parameterValue; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.GetType().Name; }
    }

    public bool ShouldInherit
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public object GetValue(IContext context, ITarget target)
    {
        return this.parameterValue;
    }

    public bool Equals(IParameter other)
    {
        return this.GetType() == other.GetType();
    }
}

public class AbstractFactoryModule : NinjectModule
{
    private const string ConfigurationScopeName = "ConfigurationScope";

    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Bind<IConfigurationFactory>().To<ConfigurationFactory>();
        this.Bind<Configuration>().ToSelf()
            .DefinesNamedScope(ConfigurationScopeName);
        this.Bind<IFactory>().ToFactory()
            .InNamedScope(ConfigurationScopeName);
        this.Bind<IProduct1>().To<Product1A>()
            .WhenProductFamiliy(ProductFamily.A);
        this.Bind<IProduct1>().To<Product1B>()
            .WhenProductFamiliy(ProductFamily.B);
    }
}

public static class AbstractFactoryBindingExtensions
{
    public static IBindingInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> WhenProductFamiliy<T>(this IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> binding, ProductFamily productFamily)
    {
        return binding
            .When(x => x.Parameters.OfType<AbstractFactoryConfigurationParameter>().Single().ProductFamily == productFamily);
    }
}
```

Please note that I am not convinced that the Named Scope is necessary for your use case. The named scope ensures that there is only one instance of a type (here: the IFactory) per scope (here: the configuration instance). So you basically get an "`IFactory` singleton per configuration".
In the above example code it certainly is not required as the factory instances are not specific to configuration. If the factories are specific to a configuration create a binding for each and also use the `.WhenProductFamily(..)` binding extension to make sure the correct factory gets injected.

Also note that you can make the `AbstractFactoryConfigurationParameter` and the `.WhenProductFamily(..)` extension more generic so you can reuse it for multiple different abstract factories.

Comment: @BatterBackupUnit Thank you very much, this solution is gorgeous and is exactly that kind of solution i was looking for. I think the missing bits were how to put in the runtime parameter correctly paired with the binding. That would have taken me a while to figure out, indeed!

FYI: I would like to vote you up for the use of `FluentAssertions` as i wasn't familiar with this, but i can't because i need 15P of reputation to do so. hehe
Thanks again
Greetings

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit quick question. If I remove the .DefinesNamedScope(ConfigurationScopeName) and .InNamedScope(ConfigurationScopeName) I get an error "Expected object to be Castle.Proxies.IFactoryProxy{}, but found Castle.Proxies.IFactoryProxy{}." at configA.component.factory.Should().Be(configA.factory);. Any idea why?

Comment: @kooshka: it's a different instance of the same factory. If you don't need there to be a "singleton per configuration" of the factory, you can get rid of the named scope stuff. It's expected then for the verification `configA.component.factory.Should().Be(configA.factory)` to fail, but the factory will still produce an `A` "product" and not a `B` product.