# How to implement custom factory method with Ninject Factory Extensions

Tags: c#, .net, ninject, factory, ninject-extensions

I have a `XmlSerializer` and a `JsonSerializer` where a factory should decide which one to instantiate based on command line parameter "json" or "xml". Pretty easy but I would like to do this with Ninjects Factory extensions.

So this is what I have working now:

```
Bind<ISerializerFactory>().ToFactory(() => new UseFirstArgumentAsNameInstanceProvider());
Bind<ISerializer>().To<XmlSerializer>().Named("xml");
Bind<ISerializer>().To<JsonSerializer>().Named("json");
```

In Composition Root I instantiate the serializer like this:

```
kernel.Get<ISerializerFactory>().CreateSerializer(options.ContentFormat);
```

So far so good.

Now I introduced something like a strategy pattern to set behaviour to a few properties of the `ISerializer` classes, like:

```
concreteSerializer.BehaviourA = new Behaviour();
```

These behaviours should be instantiated by a factory too since the behaviour is given by the user at runtime.

So I did the same factory configuration like I did with the serializer itself already.
But I want to set the behaviour instantiated by the `IBehaviourFactory` within the first `ISerializerFactory`.

So I tried something like this:

```
Bind<ISerializer>().ToMethod(context =>
            {
                var xmlSerializer = context.Kernel.Get<XmlSerializer>();
                var behaviourFactory = context.Parameters.First(x => x.Name == "behaviourFactory").GetValue(context, <ITarget??>) as IBehaviourFactory;
                xmlSerializer.BehaviourA = behaviourFactory.CreateBehaviour(optionsFromSomewhere);
                return xmlSerializer;
            }).Named("xml");
```

But I can't get it to work.

How should I set the Behaviour to the serializer when creating the serializer instance?
How should I solve such scenarios in general?

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Would it be an alternative to have it created by an abstract-factory like pattern like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954481/how-to-implement-an-gof-ish-abstract-factory-pattern-using-an-ioc-like-ninject/20968400#20968400 ?

Comment: Tried to investigate if this is what I want, but I didn't come to any conclusions ;-) Would be nice if you find the time to explain shortly how abstract factory pattern would solve my issues. I am fiddling around with the pattern meanwhile..

Comment: (i was away for a few days). From your question i'm not entirely certain on when what should be instantiated. Am i correct in assuming, that both the serializer type (xml/json) and the behavior type are passed as cmd-line args? The `ISerializer` instance should be built up completely - including behavior - at once? so you would like a factory you'd use like `ISerializer IFactory.Create("xml", "typeA")`? (For future reference: it would be helpful to always state one's goal clearly, like how the interface should look like).