# Is this a right or viable implementation of the Abstract Factory pattern?

Tags: c#, ninject, ninject-extensions, abstract-factory

Inspired from [**Mark Seemann's post: Pattern Recognition: Abstract Factory or Service Locator?**](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/11/01/PatternRecognitionAbstractFactoryorServiceLocator/)

I wish to write an abstract factory like so:

```
public interface IAbstractFactory { 
    T Create<T>();
}
```

Then, binding it using Ninject like so:

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<IAbstractFactory>().ToFactory();
```

Then, one may use it as follows:

```
public class CustomerServiceIndicatorsModel {
    public CustomerServiceIndicatorsModel(IAbstractFactory factory) {
        this.emailIndicatorA = factory.Create<EmailIndicatorA>();
        this.emailIndicatorB = factory.Create<EmailIndicatorB>();
        this.emailIndicatorC = factory.Create<EmailIndicatorC>();
    }
}
```

Again, I'm not referencing the Ninject's kernel anywhere, and this works. The kernel is only refered to in the `Global.asax.cs` file for the bindings.

Can it be considered as an acceptable implementation of the abstract factory pattern?

I have a hard time trying to get the jist of this pattern. I understand the `Factory` pattern clearly as being a delegated class which creates instances of a given type.

```
public interface IEmailIndicatorAFactory {
    EmailIndicatorA Create();
}
```

Then, when I bind it `ToFactory()` using Ninject, it shall create instances of `EmailIndicatorA`.

How to bind `IAbstractFactory<T>` using Ninject, since each type:

```
IAbstractFactory<EmailIndicatorA>
IAbstractFactory<EmailIndicatorB>
IAbstractFactory<EmailIndicatorC>
```

is considered a completely concrete type. And I can't find a way to bind it using `Ninject`.

And I don't see any benefit of writing such an interface if in return I have to write:

```
public interface EmailIndicatorAFactory : IAbstractFactory<EmailIndicatorA> { }
public interface EmailIndicatorBFactory : IAbstractFactory<EmailIndicatorB> { }
public interface EmailIndicatorCFactory : IAbstractFactory<EmailIndicatorC> { }
```

After a comment by @PrestonGuillot, I fell in the latter implementing the `ServiceLocator` instead of the `AbstractFactory` as I'm using a generic `Create<T>()` method, and the `Abstract Factory` uses a non-generic `Create()` method.

Thanks for pointing it out, @PrestonGuillot! =)

Perhaps I am overcomplicating things here... So here's my model:

**EmailIndicator**

```
public abstract EmailIndicator { 
    int EmailCount { get; set; }
    DateTime OldestDateTimeReceived { get; set; }
}
```

**EmailIndicatorA**

```
public class EmailIndicatorA : EmailIndicator { }
```

**EmailIndicatorB**

```
public class EmailIndicatorB : EmailIndicator { }
```

**EmailIndicatorC**

```
public class EmailIndicatorC : EmailIndicator { }
```

**IEmailIndicatorRepository**

```
public interface IEmailIndicatorRepository<T> where T : EmailIndicator {
    T GetIndicator();
}

public class EmailIndicatorARepository : IEmailIndicatorRepository<EmailIndicatorA> {
    public EmailIndicatorARepository(IExchangeService service
        , IExchangeConfiguration configuration
        , INetworkCredentialFactory credentialFactory) {
        exchangeService = service;
        exchangeService.Url = configuration.ExchangeUri;
        exchangeService = credentialFactory.Create(configuration.Login, configuration.Password);       
    }

    EmailIndicatorA GetIndicator() {
        // Code to query Exchange through its Web services here...
    }
}
```

And two other repository like this one exist, since I have to query three different Exchange servers in my application.

I believe there is room for using the `Abstract Factory`, and because I am still learning the pattern, I just don't get how to implement it yet in my situation.

If not for the indicators themselves, perhaps I can finally get a grasp on the `Abstract Factory` with my reposptories.

As far as my understanding goes, here's what I would try as a first step toward a solution:

**IRepositoryFactory**

```
public interface IRepositoryFactory<T> where T : class, new() {
    T Create();
}
```

**IEmailIndicatorARepositoryFactory**

```
public interface IEmailIndicatorARepositoryFactory 
    : IRepositoryFactory<EmailIndicatorARepository> {
    EmailIndicatorARepository CreateEmailIndicatorARepository();
}
```

**IEmailIndicatorBRepositoryFactory**

```
public interface IEmailIndicatorBRepositoryFactory 
    : IRepositoryFactory<EmailIndicatorBRepository> {
    EmailIndicatorBRepository CreateEmailIndicatorBRepository();
}
```

And the **Abstract Factory** ?

```
public abstract IEmailIndicatorRepositoryFactory 
    : IEmailIndicatorARepositoryFactory
    , IEmailIndicatorBRepositoryFactory
    , IEmailIndicatorCRepositoryFactory {
    EmailIndicatorARepository CreateEmailIndicatorARepository() { // create instance here... }
    EmailIndicatorBRepository CreateEmailIndicatorBRepository() { // create instance here... }
    EmailIndicatorCRepository CreateEmailIndicatorCRepository() { // create instance here... }
}
```

Is this a better approach?

I'm kind of lost and confused here.

Comment: If you need instances of `EmailIndicatorA`, `EmailIndicatorB`, and `EmailIndicatorC` to create an instance of `CustomerServiceIndicatorsModel`, why wouldn't you just have those in the constructor? It looks like you aren't doing anything that necessitates an abstract factory from your snippet.

Comment: You're right. Perhaps my example is not very well chosen and I couldn't think of anything else from the top of my head. Besides, what about the implementation of the `Abstract Factory` pattern?

Comment: Regardless, the blog post you link answers your question fairy directly "An Abstract Factory is a generic type *with a non-generic Create method*; a Service Locator is a *non-generic type with a generic Create method.*", you fall into the latter.

Comment: On second thought, you're right. I must have gotten confused along the way. I have a hard time getting the jist of the `Abstract Factory` pattern and its benefits.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot: Please see my question edit. =)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698026/is-the-service-locator-pattern-any-different-from-the-abstract-factory-pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm finding the diagrams of the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) quite enlightening.

I think the name "Abstract Factory" is a bit misleading in the .net / c# world. You only need an `abstract class` in case the language doesn't support interfaces or you want to share implementation (but remember [favor composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)).

Since you mentioned Mark Seeman i'd like to distill my interpretation of a few of his posts regarding IoC and Factory:

- don't use service locator

  - hides dependencies
  - [Interface segregation principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)
- create a composition root. Ideally it should instantiate all objects in one go at the beginning.

  - as such you should design your objects to be stateless and only process data - whenever possible (separation of data and processing logic). That means you only have to instantiate more or less data classes / data structs, which don't have any dependencies. All the objects with dependencies are created in one go upon application start up.
- late creation is *not* failing fast

  - if you use late creation, whether you call it service locator or factory, this decreases testability, since issues will not be visible upon application startup but rather only when you're using/creating the object at a later time.
  - to remedy this somewhat, create all dependencies of the object to be created by the factory already @composition root. Only late-create the actual object.
  - this is done using the abstract factory pattern.

So given your example this would be:

```
public interface IEmailIndicatorFactory
{
    IEmailIndicator Create();
}
```

with three implementations, one for `EmailIndicatorA`, `EmailIndicatorB` and `EmailIndicatorC` each. Now to make the argument matter, the `EmailIndicator` needs a dependency specific to `EmailIndicatorA`, (or B, C). Let's say it requires `IServiceA`:

```
internal class EmailIndicatorA : IEmailIndicator
{
    private readonly IServiceA serviceA;

    public EmailIndicatorA(IServiceA serviceA)
    {
        this.serviceA = serviceA;
    }

    (...)
}
```

Now there should be a corresponding factory which receives the dependencies of `EmailIndicatorA`:

```
internal class EmailIndicatorAFactory : IEmailIndicatorFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceA serviceA;

    public EmailIndicatorAFactory(IServiceA serviceA)
    {
        this.serviceA = serviceA;
    }

    public IEmailIndicator Create()
    {
        return new EmailIndicatorA(this.serviceA);
    }
}
```

That's it. If `EmailIndicatorA` had additional dependencies, they should be injected into `EmailIndicatorAFactory`, too.

Now the benefit of doing all of this code is fail-fast.
All the other issues can be addressed by correct use of `.ToFactory()` bindings and interfaces which aren't too generic but specific instead (well basically the same ones as with the abstract factory above!).

I think you should carefully weigh the pro's and con's.

Mark also said that he's using IoC containers seldomly anymore. Instead he most often prefers poor man's di. See [this post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer/).

I think Mark is very good at pointing out pro's and con's and reading his posts is very educational. I don't agree with all his conclusions, but TBH I would love to work with him on a project for a while (not just a few weeks, longer) and *then* see whether i agree or not.

Having said that i would like to offer you an alternative way to handle the use cases for the abstract factory pattern. Since i've already posted it on SO before there's nothing left to do but to [link it :)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20968400/684096)

As a last note, i don't know of any IoC container which features `Func<>` or interface factories like Ninject's `.ToFactory()` which early instantiate the dependencies. It is only done once you execute the `Func<>` or call the `IFooFactory.CreateFoo()` method.
So the issue of fail-fast has not yet been addressed by auto-generated factories.
However, what has been done is that some containers have verification methods which verify that types can be instantiated and that there are no [Captive Dependencies](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/). For example [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org)

Comment: Inspired by your approach, I finally decided to go forward with the use of providers which I find is an easier way to go, though it actually serves the same purpose, that is, instantiating instances based on some kind of context or dependencies. On a side note, I always appreciate your answers. They always have enlightened my path toward a more proper use of DI and IoC. Thank you.